# Include user details in AWS Cognito Oauth2 token

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS cognito with a NodeJS backend API and want to include user details in the access token return from */oauth2/token* end point with scopes defined in the user pool client app.

Also if I use *adminInitiateAuth* API, there is no way to include the scopes in the return access token. So is it possible to have both user details and scopes in a one access token?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito does not support custom claims in access tokens, which I think is a really good design choice.

You can manage extra / custom data fairly easily in your APIs and UIs in a much more extensible manner via claims caching:
https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/

There is a node sample of mine that does this here:
https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2

It is a pattern often implemented by API gateways, such as AWS:
https://authguidance.com/2018/12/16/serverless-api-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Cognito returns multiple tokens uppon succesful autehntication : an ID token, an Access Token, and optionaly a Refresh Token.

**Question 1 : user details in Token**

The ID Token contains the some PII details, such as the use name and email address.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

When using [AWS amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/), you can use `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` to retrieve user details from Cognito

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

**Question 2 : adminInitiateAuth**

This is currently not supported
https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/477

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it recommended to use **AWS amplify** in a backend application?

Comment: AWS amplify is a command line tool and a client side library to make the life of front end developer easier.  It simplifies the provisioning of cloud infrastructure.  So if you are a full stack dev and your project is front end driven, I do recommend to use AWS Amplify.  If your project is driven by the backend or you're not part of the front end dev team, have alook at SAM

Comment: if I move into the backend approach, will it be possible to authenticate users with Google or Facebook? if yes can you please explain the correct approach.

Comment: sure you can.  there are tons of blog post explaining how to do that.  This one for example https://medium.com/@jameshamann/serverless-react-web-app-with-aws-amplify-part-three-d3f1a30176e8