# AWS Cognito - using scopes in authorizing access to api gateway

Tags: oauth-2.0, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have setup a Cognito user pool so that I can use it to authorize access the an api gateway. It uses OAUTH2 and the flow im using is : Authorization Code Grant,
Scopes : email, openid and profile,
Allowed Custom Scope : product-api/read_product, product-api/create_product, product-api/delete_product

I use boto3 admin_initiate_auth command to connect to the user pool:-

```
response = idpclient.admin_initiate_auth(
UserPoolId=USERPOOLID,
AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
AuthParameters={
'USERNAME':USERNAME,
'PASSWORD':PASSWORD,
'SECRET_HASH':SECRET_HASH
},
ClientId=APPCLIENTID
)
```

and the response I receive is a json object with several fields, which include access_token, refresh_token etc...

but when I use the access_token to access the api gateway, i get a 401 error. Unauthorised. Looking into the access_token it looks like the custom scopes have not been added.

Could you advise why the custom scope has not been added to the access_token and how do i get the custom scopes added ?

the api gateway has a lambda authorizer added.

Comment: Dumb question, but is the resource you're trying to access on API Gateway within your custom scope?

Comment: Thanks for your reply !  Yes, checked that.  thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have to specify the Scopes in 2 places:

- The OAuth client entry for the client application  in the Cognito section of the AWS console
- The code requesting a token - I have always implemented this in a standards based manner whereas you are using an AWS specific solution

Looks like what you want may not be supported via admin_initiate_oauth:
[Include user details in AWS Cognito Oauth2 token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168057/include-user-details-in-aws-cognito-oauth2-token)

If your client application is a web UI then the standards based solution will do what you want.

I've tested my Cognito single page app sample with custom scopes - you can run it here:
https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart

Not sure if this type of solution will work for you though ..

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your reply !  With regards to admin_initiate_auth... i had a suspicion this might be the case.  And although this may sound strange, but i hadnt thought that i needed to add the custom scopes to the code.  Im going to have a look at the docs for boto3 and see if i can somehow add the scopes.  if not, i may just have to somehow use the python request object to connect with cognito and get he access_token that way...  thanks again for your help